# Reading\writing to external app.config files

Tags: vb.net

I need to read the keys from several external applications .config files, is it possible to specify the file for AppSettingsReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that's not possible, but they're just XML files so it's fairly easy to do using the standard XML classes.

If you've not used the XML classes before, here's a sample to get you started: [Read a .NET .Config file as an XML document to get the application's Runtime Version](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/RuntimeVersion.aspx)